# Definition of ciphertext security

Tags: block-cipher, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

If I got it right, chosen ciphertext security implies also CPA security. In other words, attacker can submit plaintexts to the challenger (along with ciphertexts).

[image]

I do not understand why encryption system (E,D) where D(k,0)=0 is considered as ciphertext secure.

Imagine CPA security game where an attacker just submits two plaintexts, m0 = 0 and m1 = (any value != 0). In that case if poor challenger returns 0 then we are certain that we're in experiment 0 and win CPA game.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Where do you get the idea from that such a scheme would be CCA secure?

Comment: Such schemes can't provide [plaintext integrity](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs276-s06/l9.pdf) (and thus also can't provide ciphertext integrity), but that has very little to do with IND-CPA. $\;$

Comment: @Maeher, I added a screenshot.

Comment: Where does it state in the screenshot that such a scheme is secure?

Comment: @Maeher, it does not state here that D(k,0)=0 is considered as ciphertext secure. However it was stated in the problem set in crypto class. I gave apparently wrong answer, and as an explanation I got "Consider a chosen ciphertext secure encryption system (E,D) where D(k,0)=0."

Comment: That's not suggesting that security follows from D(k,0)=0; it should be interpreted as "Consider a chosen ciphertext secure encryption system (E,D) where" it happens to be the case that for all keys k, D(k,0)=0. $\hspace{.16 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Hm.. I still don't get it. Do you mean that if D(k,0)=0 then (E, D) is not a CCA secure?

Comment: No, I mean for all encryption schemes (E,D), there is an encryption scheme (E',D') such that [[for all keys k, D'(k,0)=0] and [if (E,D) is IND-CPA then (E',D') is IND-CPA] and [if (E,D) is CCA secure then (E',D') is CCA secure]]. $\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to note here is that $\mathsf{D}(k,0)=0$ does **not** necessarily imply that $\mathsf{E}(k,0)=0$. That is the reason why your attack does not work in general.

To illustrate, let $(\mathsf{E},\mathsf{D})$ be a CCA secure encryption scheme.
We then construct a new encryption scheme $(\mathsf{E'},\mathsf{D'})$ as follows:
$$\mathsf{E'}(k,m) = 1\Vert \mathsf{E}(k,m)$$ and
$$\mathsf{D'}(k,b\Vert c) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0& \text{if } b = 0\\ \mathsf{D}(k,c)& \text{if } b = 1\end{array}\right.$$

It is trivial to show via reduction that $(\mathsf{E'},\mathsf{D'})$ inherits the CCA security from $(\mathsf{E},\mathsf{D})$, but still it has the property that $\mathsf{D'}(k,0)=0$.

As you can see, your attack does not work, because $0$ is never **encrypted** to $0$ by the challenger.

Comment: ... and D'(k,empty_string)=0. $\;$